# How to intuitively visualize open maps

Tags: analysis, soft-question

I intuitively think of continuous maps as functions whose behavior as they approach a point is the same as their behavior at the point. How should I intuitively think of open maps?

Comment: I am not sure whether what you gave is a good interpretation of continuous functions. Maybe try thinking of them as functions s.t. if $x$ gets close to $y$, then $f(x)$ gets close to $f(y)$. However, a continuous function may have the property that $f(x)$ gets close to $f(y)$ dispite $x$ and $y$ not being close.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What exactly do you not like about my intuition of continuous functions? Isn't it very similar to your interpretation of if x gets close to y, then f(x) gets close to f(y)

Comment: The problem I am having is that it is rather imprecise. Consider for example the map $f: [0,2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ given by $t \mapsto e^{it}$. This map is continuous, but around the point $(1,0)$, the map brings $0$ and points that are close to $2 \pi$ (i.e. points that are far apart)  very close together.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with infinitesimals, either informally or as formalized in, say, Robinson's non-standard analysis, that can provide some geometric intuition.

Thus:

> "$f$ is continuous at $x_0$ when, for any $x$ infinitesimally close to $x_0$, $f(x)$ is infinitesimally close to $f(x_0)$."

(The formal version of this appears in Robinson, *Non-standard Analysis*, p.66. The technical statement includes a fine point or two.)

So if you picture $x_0$ as a dot, and all the $x$'s infinitesimally close to $x_0$ as a "fuzzy dot", this says that the image of the fuzzy dot is *contained* in a fuzzy dot around $f(x_0)$. In other words, $f$ can't "blow up the infinitesimal neighborhood of $x_0$ to finite size".

Being open is the flip side: images of fuzzy dots "remain fuzzy". For example, consider $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$. This is open except at $x=0$. The image of the fuzzy dot centered at 0 is "folded over" by $f$, so it looks fuzzy on the right but has a sharp edge on the left.